# How can I fix E: Invalid operation –-fix-missing?

Tags: apt, 19.10

I am trying to run the command `sudo apt-get –-fix-missing` and got the output `E: Invalid operation –-fix-missing`. Then I tried `sudo apt -–fix-missing` and got `E: Command line option '�' [from -–fix-missing] is not understood in combination with the other options.`. How do I fix this

Also, the weird question mark isn't StackExchange messing up. It is appearing in my terminal

Edit: Now I get the output of `sudo apt-get`

Comment: Did you copy-paste the command from a website? it looks like it has a Unicode EN DASH in place of a regular hyphen. Try actually typing it instead.

Comment: And there should be an `install` there

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I did. Now when I manually type it, I get the output of ```sudo apt-get```

Comment: @muru, That worked, I will add a comment and mark it as solved